# Angular2/Nativescript: TypeError from a Rest service that works without any issues in a web app

Tags: rest, angular, angular2-nativescript

I am busy with a small app that talks to a local server.  When the app starts I check for a IP address in LocalStorage using the Nativescript-localstorage module...  If the IP hasn't been set the app then navigates to a settings view where the IP can be entered.  When the IP is entered and a submit button is tapped the IP is used in a GET method of a /ping enddpoint of a Rest service that confirms that the correct IP was entered/that the server is up...  I keep getting the following error:

```
error:

TypeError:  error.json is not a function
```

i'm guessing this happens in my Rest service's ping function but can't figure out why...  This service works fine with no errors in another web app.  Any idea what could be causing this?

UPDATE:
So it seems like I only get this error when entering the correct IP.  When I enter a random incorrect IP I get 'server error' as the response...

```
my code:

settings.component.ts:

import { Component,} from '@angular/core';

import { RestService } from '../../services/rest.service';
import { LocalStorageService } from '../../services/local-storage.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'settings',
  templateUrl: './pages/settings/settings.component.html'
})
export class SettingsComponent {
  ipSaved: boolean = false;
  error: boolean = false;
  ip: string;

  constructor(private restService: RestService, private localStorageService: LocalStorageService) {

    }

    submitIP() {
        if (this.ip !== null && this.ip !== ''){
            console.log("ip before get: " + this.ip);
            this.restService.ping(this.ip)
            .subscribe(
                (res) => {

                    this.localStorageService.saveLocalIP(this.ip);
                    this.restService.init(this.ip);
                    this.ipSaved = true;
                },
                (res) => {
                    console.log(res);
                    this.error = true;
                }
            );      
        console.log("ip: " + this.localStorageService.findLocalIP());
        } else {
            alert("Warning: IP field can't be empty!");
        }
    }

    dismissError() {
        this.error = false;
    }


}


settings.component.html:

<StackLayout class="page">
<Label class="h1 title m-x-auto " text="Settings"></Label>
<StackLayout class="form" *ngIf="!IPSaved && !error">
<StackLayout class="input-field">
<TextField class="input input-border" placeholder="Enter IP" [(ngModel)]="ip"></TextField>
</StackLayout>
<Button class="btn btn-primary" text="Submit" (tap)="submitIP()"></Button>
</StackLayout>
<StackLayout *ngIf="IPSaved && !error">
    <Label class="h1" text="IP Saved successfully"></Label>
    <Button class="btn btn-primary" text="Done" [nsRouterLink]="['/home']"></Button>
</StackLayout>
<StackLayout *ngIf="error">
<Label class="body text-danger" text="ERROR:  The IP address entered doesn't seem to be correct.  Make sure the device is connected to the local wireless network and try again..."></Label>
<Button class="btn btn-primary" (tap)="dismissError()"></Button>
</StackLayout>

</StackLayout>


my ping function from my rest.service.ts:


ping(ip: string) : Observable<Response> {
      let tempApiUrl: string = "http://" + ip + "/BRMServices/WebEnquiry/ping";
      return this.http.get(tempApiUrl, this.headers)
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing `error.json().error` with simply `error`?

Comment: @Eddy Verbruggen When I do that I get SyntaxError: unexpected A in json at position 0...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the type of the error object in the catch block. In your code it is of type **any** which is invalid. Instead it should also be of type Response as below.

```
ping(ip: string) : Observable<Response> {
      let tempApiUrl: string = "http://" + ip + "/BRMServices/WebEnquiry/ping";
      return this.http.get(tempApiUrl, this.headers)
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      // below line is modified
      .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
  }
```

Comment: that didn't make any difference...  If you look at the || 'server error' i'm guessing that won't be a Response object?

Comment: So the strange thing is it seems I only get this error when I enter the correct IP.  When I enter a incorrect IP I get 'server error'...